# JsonServiceClient returns reponse with correct attribute but empty value

Tags: c#, json, servicestack

I am trying to make a JSON request on an external service, that would look like this :

GET request :

```
https://remotehost/path/mycount?foo=C&bar=21
```

response :

```
{"count":1000}
```

for this, I use ServiceStack JsonServiceClient, here is my code below

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(classifiedSearchBaseURL);
var response = client.Get<CountResponse>(new MyRequest {
    foo = "C",
    bar = 21
});

class MyRequest
{    
    public string foo { get; set; }
    public int bar { get; set; }
}

class CountResponse
{
    public string count;
}
```

The problem is that I get a response object with an attribute "count" that is null, even though the server answers a 200 with a correct value/response (using Fiddler)

I tried changing the type of count from string to int but then I get 0 instead of null.

Any of you guys have an idea?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

ServiceStack only serializes **public properties** by default so you need to change your Response DTO to:

```
class CountResponse
{
    public string count { get; set; }
}
```

I'd also recommend adding the `IReturn<T>` marker interfaces like:

```
class MyRequest : IReturn<CountResponse>
{    
    public string foo { get; set; }
    public int bar { get; set; }
}
```

So the Response Type can be automatically inferred by the client so your call sites can be reduced to:

```
var response = client.Get(new MyRequest { foo = "C", bar = 21 });
```

Comment: Never would have guessed that myself ! Thanks mythz !!

Just a C# question then, can you redirect me to the theory regarding public properties and why adding get and set changes everything ?

Comment: @AlexandreG they’re the public API contract of your class and what’s used to define the shape of your DTOs. In .NET coding guidelines it’s recommended to always have external classes bind to public properties as it’s binary and source compatible to later modify your property into a calculated property or one with a backing field, whereas it would be a breaking change had you used a field.

Comment: @mythz do you recommend use of internal properties on request DTOs?

Comment: @labilbe internal properties don't contribute towards the purpose of DTOs which is to define your Services Contract and its serialized form, so internal members or any implementations for that matter don't belong in DTOs. Implementations can be useful if you need to control serialization for a specific format but in those cases it breaks the general purpose utilities of DTOs for other formats and languages.

Comment: @mythz I say this because sometimes, I need to pass a request.MyObject (internal) instead of request.MyObjectId (public) (for performance reasons). But I finally resolved this using helper methods.